# Create a Json as input to an Html Datatable

Tags: jquery-plugins

Within jQuery, I am attempting to create Json data below but having some difficulty as it relates to the jQuery plugin "DataTables".

Please see this URL for a similar example: http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

My Json based variable should be used as input into the follow DataTable, but it's not working (i.e. my Datatables Html table does not render):

```
// JSON DATA OF PORTFOLIOS !!
$(this).find("exposureProfile node").each(function () {  
      PfJsonData.aaData.push({
                "PfId": pfId,
                "Name": name,
                "ExpType": expType,
                "Date": nodeDate,
                "Term": term,
                "Exposure": exposure
            });
});

var oTable = $('#pftable').dataTable({             
        "aaData": [PfJsonData],             // "aaData" paramater here !!        
        "aoColumns":[
            { "mData": "PfId" },
            { "mData": "Name" },
            { "mData": "ExpType" },
            { "mData": "Date" },
            { "mData": "Term" },
            { "mData": "Exposure" }
        ],
        'aoColumnDefs': [                              
            { "sTitle": "Pf Id", "aTargets": [0] },    
            { "sTitle": "Name", "aTargets": [1] },
            { "sTitle": "Exp Type", "aTargets": [2] },
            { "sTitle": "Date", "aTargets": [3] },
            { "sTitle": "Term", "aTargets": [4] },
            { "sTitle": "Exposure", "aTargets": [5] },
        ]
    });
```

The above code will simply NOT render my Datatables Html table. However, if I manually create the data inline it will work just fine. Here's an example, pointing out the "aaData" parameter only:

```
         "aaData": [
        {
            "PfId": "11000",
            "Name": "Bob Jr.",
            "ExpType": "Hs Var",
            "Date": "05/01/1967",
            "Term": "term 123",
            "Exposure": "55,000,000"
        },
        {
            "PfId": "12000",
            "Name": "James",
            "ExpType": "Hs Var",
            "Date": "06/14/2003",
            "Term": "term 123",
            "Exposure": "56,000,000"
        }
        ],
```

Can someone help me with this if possible ? I hope my question is clear enough.

Regards,
Bob

Answer (score 0):

Because of your usage, I assume PfJsonData.aaData is an array itself, in which case I wonder why you don't simply use:

```
"aaData": PfJsonData.aaData,
```

The existing code seems to put an object inside a newly created array that is mapped to by aaData, which I wouldn't expect to work.